# Execute 2 commands on bind in bashrc

Tags: bash, readline

I want to expand aliases automatically, when press Space key. In .bashrc I have following line

```bash
bind '" ": alias-expand-line'
```

it changes alias with actual command(f.e. opbashrc changes with vim ~/.bashrc), but if I write for example 'cp', press Space, nothing happens = Space doesn't apper. I found, that there is also command "self-insert". But I don't know how to run 2 commands at once, something like this doesn't work

```bash
bind '" ": self-insert && alias-expand-line'
```

Comment: There is a `-x` option to `bind` that lets you specify an arbitrary shell command when a key is pressed, but I don't think there is any interface to allow the shell to execute an arbitrary Readline function.

Comment: There is a `magic-space` command that performs *history* expansion *and* inserts a space. That wouldn't be necessary if there were a way to compose the existing `history-expand-line` and `self-insert` commands, so I'm not sure `bash`/Readline supports what you want to do.